# Duplicate packages in Haskell environment?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I put [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781783286331/1/ch01lvl1sec17/learning-how-to-perform-http-post-requests) in a file (see bottom) and got the following error when loading it in ghci (i.e. start ghci then `:l file`):

```
7:13: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘network-uri-2.6.1.0@network-uri-2.6.1.0-7BN1tbB3iHQ2XgvmqLAYph:Network.URI.URI’
                  with actual type ‘Network.URI.URI’
      NB: ‘Network.URI.URI’
            is defined in ‘Network.URI’
                in package ‘network-uri-2.6.1.0@network-uri-2.6.1.0-80FpvaNUTSDFCPv0sSze40’
          ‘network-uri-2.6.1.0@network-uri-2.6.1.0-7BN1tbB3iHQ2XgvmqLAYph:Network.URI.URI’
            is defined in ‘Network.URI’
                in package ‘network-uri-2.6.1.0@network-uri-2.6.1.0-7BN1tbB3iHQ2XgvmqLAYph’
```

Have I somehow installed two slightly different versions of network-uri, or what is this? How do I resolve it?

I've hardly used cabal but tried `cabal install --reinstall network-uri`, went fine but problem persists.

File contents:

```hs
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI (parseURI)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
myRequestURL = "http://www.virginia.edu/cgi-local/ldapweb"
myRequest :: String -> Request_String
myRequest query = Request {
    rqURI = fromJust $ parseURI myRequestURL
  , rqMethod = POST
  , rqHeaders = [ mkHeader HdrContentType "text/html"
                , mkHeader HdrContentLength $ show $ length body ]
  , rqBody = body
  }
  where body = "whitepages=" ++ query
main :: IO ()
main = do
  response <- simpleHTTP $ myRequest "poon"
  putStrLn ""
```

**EDIT** Re-installed haskell-platform. After this, `ghc-pkg list` reports all packages to be under (?) `/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d`, and the program I tried to copy loads just fine.

**EDIT 2** After running `cabal install some-pkg`, `ghc-pkg list` reports that the newly installed stuff is in another directory. Indeed, `~/.cabal/config` specifies install dirs for user, as well as install dirs for global. How is all this supposed to be managed properly?

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list` say?

Comment: It says ```/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d network-uri-2.6.1.0 ... /home/evesterl/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.0.2/package.conf.d network-uri-2.6.1.0```, I guess that might have something to do with the problem? No idea how to fix it though (or how I got in that mess).

Comment: I'm a bit lost about where the edits leave us. Are things working for you now or not? If not, can you simply adjust the question to be a self-contained description of the current state of affairs, rather than this account which requires readers to piece together details from three different points in time?

Comment: @DanielWagner From the first edit it follows that the program loads, in the second edit a hint was given as to what caused the problem. The original problem, "how do I resolve it", still stands (re-install doesn't count as resolution).

Answer (score 6):

GHC understands the concept of package databases. Cabal manages multiple package databases. There's a system package database, and a user package database. When you compile something with Cabal V1, it uses the union of these package databases. This is a bit of a time bomb, because, as you see, GHC does not like it when you have multiple of the same package. When you issued `cabal install network-uri`, `cabal` decided to install one copy of that package into your user database, though you already had one in the system database. When you tried to use `ghc`, it picked up on the two copies and got confused. Because `cabal` does not support removing packages, your Haskell installation was pretty much borked, and you reinstalled. I believe you could have done a more conservative `rm ~/.ghc`, or, had you been really adventurous, used the low-level `ghc-pkg` command to edit the package database.

Now that you've reinstalled the Platform, I would heavily recommend *never using `cabal install` again*. It's old, it's broken, `cabal` itself tells you not to use it. If you're using the Platform, I think it has `stack` in it, which is a different build manager, based on Cabal, which is not prone to this kind of breakage. Or, you can just stick to the V2 series of `cabal` commands, which is what I prefer.

Cabal V2 does not directly support your usecase, where you install a package globally and compile a program against it. This is because doing so is fundamentally broken: global package databases really just don't work for GHC. What Cabal V2 does is install packages into your home directory, `~/.cabal/store`. You then have to explicitly tell it which packages you want, and it will construct a package database that contains each required package, without any wonkiness. You can get a REPL with a certain set of packages by issuing (this will take you to a temporary directory; you may need to `:cd` yourself back.)

```
cabal v2-repl -b network-uri -b package2 -b etc
```

If you want to actually compile files with `ghc` with a set packages, you have to actually define a package with a `.cabal` file. Here's a stub `.cabal` file:

```
name:          temporary-pkg
version:       0.0.0.0
build-type:    Simple
cabal-version: >=2.0
executable main -- if there is no Main, say "library" instead of "executable <name>"
  default-language: Haskell2010
  main-is:          Main.hs -- only valid in executable stanzas
  hs-source-dirs:   src -- source files go here
  build-depends:    base, network-uri, package2, etc -- packages go here
```

Create and enter a directory, place that in `temporary-pkg.cabal`, place your sources in `src/`, and you can issue stuff like `cabal v2-build` and `cabal v2-repl` and `cabal v2-exec main`, etc. `cabal` will go off and install dependencies from Hackage into `~/.cabal/store` as needed. `cabal v2-install` is therefore not that useful here. In general, `v2-install`ing libraries is unnecessary, but `v2-install`ing packages with executables is useful. Again, for hygiene reasons, you have to list all the packages you are `import`ing from, but you don't need to list *their* dependencies or anything insane like that.

Cabal V2 still doesn't support uninstalling packages, though the point is that should not be necessary. However, if you find `~/.cabal/store` getting too large for your liking, you can just nuke it, and should be built back up as packages are requested.